# sending select_tag value on button push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a part of my rails application that isn't really a form, but it needs to send data back to my controller when I hit a button.

Right now, I can get this to work:

```
= link_to "Action", action_path(@object, :selection => 4), :method => :put
```

But I want to add in a `select_tag` to that page, and have this `link_to` send back the current value of that select tag as an additional parameter.

How would I go about doing that?

EDIT

The reason that I'm not using a form is that I have one dropdown, but multiple link_to options, each of which should pass that dropdown value.  For example, a dropdown for "Number of Shirts" and then a button for each size (S, M, L, XL) called 'Add to Cart' that would automatically post the size and selected number back to the server

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827138/rails-3-make-a-link-to-using-selected-value-from-collection-select) might help you out.

Comment: What's the reason for not using a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ajax request using jquery. Grab all the input values from the view (in your case the select tag value) and wrap it around as a parameter in the ajax request. Make sure you call the ajax function on the click of the link.

```
$('#action_link').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'my_url/process_request',
      data: { select_box_val: $("#select_box_id").val() },
      success:function(data){
      alert('ok')
      },
      error:function(){
        $('#ajax_response').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
      }
    });
});
```